# OHLC tooltip getting duplicated to volume chart also in stock chart (highstock)?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, tooltip

I am trying a custom tooltip to my stock chart. 
Like: ( my custom tooltip formatter)

```
formatter: function() {
            var extremes = $(element[0]).highcharts().xAxis[0].getExtremes(),
                           start = extremes.min,
                           end   = extremes.max;
            var toolTipObj = computeDynamicToolTip(start, end);
            return ['<b>' + convertMillisToDateFormat(this.x) + '</b>'].concat(
                    this.points.map(function(point) {
                      return 'Rainfall ' + '<b>' + point.y.toFixed(2) + '<b>' +' (mm)' + '<br>'
                            + 'High ' + '<b>' + toolTipObj.max.toFixed(2) + '<b>' + ' (mm)' + '<br>'
                            + 'Low ' + '<b>' + toolTipObj.min.toFixed(2) + '<b>' + ' (mm)' + '<br>'
                            + 'Average ' + '<b>' + toolTipObj.avg.toFixed(2) + '<b>' + ' (mm)';
                    })
                    );
          },
```

But the formatter adds tooltip to both ohlc and volume, i want to create a separate tooltip for my volume chart, so I am not able to understand how to do that.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can define a tooltip for a specific series and use `pointFormatter` to customize it:

```
    series: [{
        ...
    }, {
        type: 'column',
        ...,
        tooltip: {
            pointFormatter: function() {
                return 'some custom value'
            }
        }
    }]
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/za8126vr/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.column.tooltip.pointFormatter